# How to call a scala function taking a value of Void type

Tags: scala, void

How to call such a scala function?

```
def f(v: Void): Unit = {println(1)}
```

I haven't found a value of Void type in Scala yet.

Comment: `f(null)`  maybe?

Comment: Works like a charm! But why `null` works, how is it related to `Void`?

Comment: Type `Null` (of which `null` is an instance) is a subclass for all reference types (http://docs.scala-lang.org/resources/images/classhierarchy.img_assist_custom.png). `Void` is a reference type (a subclass of `Object`, aka `AnyRef`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe using `Void`/`null` in Java is similar to using `Unit`/`()` in Scala. Consider this:

```
abstract class Fun<A> {
  abstract public A apply();
}

class IntFun extends Fun<Integer> {
  public Integer apply() { return 0; }  
}

public static <A> A m(Fun<A> x) { return x.apply(); }
```

Now that we defined generic method `m` we also want to use it for classes where `apply` is only useful for its side effects (i.e. we need to return something that clearly indicates it's useless). `void` doesn't work as it breaks `Fun<A>` contract. We need a class with only one value which means "drop return value", and it's `Void` and `null`:

```
class VoidFun extends Fun<Void> {
  public Void apply() { /* side effects here */ return null; }  
}
```

So now we can use `m` with `VoidFun`.

In Scala usage of `null` is discouraged and `Unit` is used instead (it has only one value `()`), so I believe the method you mentioned was intended to be called from Java. To be compatible with Java Scala has `null` which is the only instance of a class `Null`. Which in turn is a subtype of any reference class, so you can assign `null` to any reference class variable. So the pattern `Void`/`null` works in Scala too.

Answer (score 1):

`Void`, or more specifically, `java.lang.Void`, has the following in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

In Scala, there's no keyword `void`, so the `Void` type is essentially useless in Scala. The closest thing is either a function with no parameters, i.e. `def f: Unit = {println(1)}` which you can call using `f` or `f()`, or the `Unit` type for functions that don't return anything, as in your example.

Comment: I was reading a [function](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/blob/master/adam-core/src/main/scala/org/bdgenomics/adam/converters/FastqRecordConverter.scala#L61) that take a value of `Void` type in another codebase, so I made up a simpler one for testing.

Comment: Does the function actually run when you call `f(_)`, or does it create a partially applied function? EDIT: I also realize I didn't really answer your question :)

Comment: No, you're right. I am still wrong. Can you help me take a look at a [function](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/blob/master/adam-core/src/main/scala/org/bdgenomics/adam/converters/FastqRecordConverter.scala#L61) above and comment what's going on?

Comment: Well, you can probably run the partially applied function, i.e. `val pF = f(_)` then just run `pF()`

Comment: Does it work for you? I still get error: `<console>:14: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: Void)Unit in trait Function1.`

Comment: Yes i realized it later, the function will still be partially applied... Trying something else now

Comment: @zyxue ugh I don't know if it's possible, I tried `f(java.lang.Void.TYPE.newInstance)` but that throws a `java.lang.InstantiationException: void`, can you avoid `Void` in any way?

Comment: I was trying to test the function mentioned above I don't know why was used in that function

Comment: That's a scala function, I think it's safe to say that no scala code should ever use the `Void` type, unless I'm missing something. You can't edit the function?

Comment: It's written by other people, so there will be functions calling it. An object returned by `sc.newAPIHadoopFile`. See [here](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/blob/master/adam-core/src/main/scala/org/bdgenomics/adam/rdd/ADAMContext.scala#L639)