# Convert Scala Unit to Java Void

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, typesafe

I have a Java class which takes `Function[String, Void]`, which is similar to `Consumer` functional interface. I am calling this Java function from Scala code. As you can see below, I accept `function: => Unit` on Scala side as it is void equivalent. When I attempt to apply this function in place of `Void` return type type mismatch happens. Explicit casting of `.asInstanceOf[Void]` also threw an exception. How do we convert `=> Unit` to `=> Void`?

```
// Java 
class AcceptFunction {
   public void temp(Function<String, Void> f) {
      f.apply("Hello");
   }
}

// Scala
def temp(f: String => Unit): Unit = {
   new AcceptFunction().temp(new Function[String, Void]() {
   override def apply(t: String): Void = f(t) // <===== error expecting Void instead of Unit
   })
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `.asInstanceOf[(String) => Void]`?

Comment: cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735812/how-to-call-a-scala-function-taking-a-value-of-void-type

Comment: "I have a Java class which takes Function[String, Void], which is similar to Consumer functional interface." Then this class should be using `Consumer`. If you can't change it, at least be aware it's a bad design and be careful with this library. "as it is void equivalent" Yes, it's equivalent to `void`, not `Void`. So you get a type mismatch just as if you used a Java method returning `void`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'd like to understand the interoperability, but I'm too lazy b/c I don't need it. My suspicion is that string => unit should be easy. Maybe your answer should be canonical?

Comment: @som-snytt I've extended it to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently,

```
scala> new jfunc.Acceptor().f(s => println(s))
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Void
       new jfunc.Acceptor().f(s => println(s))
                                          ^

scala> new jfunc.Acceptor().f { s => println(s) ; null }
hello, world.
```

where the java is like you show:

```
package jfunc;

import java.util.function.*;

public class Acceptor {
  public void f(Function<String, Void> g) { g.apply("hello, world."); }
}
```

it does:

```
scala> :javap -c -
  public static final java.lang.Void $anonfun$res0$1(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #33                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
       3: aload_0
       4: invokevirtual #37                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
       7: aconst_null
       8: areturn

  public $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #39                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #41                 // Field MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
       8: aload_0
       9: new           #43                 // class jfunc/Acceptor
      12: dup
      13: invokespecial #44                 // Method jfunc/Acceptor."<init>":()V
      16: invokedynamic #63,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;
      21: invokevirtual #67                 // Method jfunc/Acceptor.f:(Ljava/util/function/Function;)V
      24: getstatic     #72                 // Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
      27: putfield      #74                 // Field res0:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
      30: return
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)  not `Function` type, since your `Function` has no output, and `Consumer` is used for this scenario. like:

```
class AcceptFunction {
   public void temp(Consumer<String> f) { // Consumer for no output Function
      f.accept("Hello");
   }
}
def temp(f: String => Unit): Unit = {
   new AcceptFunction().temp(new Consumer[String]() {
   override def accept(t: String): Unit= f(t)    
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I was curious why above implementation did not work.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Java class which takes `Function[String, Void]`, which is similar to `Consumer` functional interface.

Then this class should be using `Consumer`. To a first approximation, `Function<String, Void>` is never the right type to use. If you can't change it, at least be aware it's a bad design and be careful with this library. Som-snytt's answer already shows how to correctly call `temp` from Scala, and it's simple to write an implicit conversion from `String => Unit` to `Function[String, Void]` if desired. So the rest of this answer is about why your other attempts didn't work.

> as it is void equivalent

Precisely: it's equivalent to `void`, not `Void`. Equivalent Java code would call a `void` method, e.g. `Consumer.accept`:

```
public void tempOfVoid(Consumer<String> f) {
    temp(new Function<String, Void> {
        public Void apply(String x) {
            return f.accept(x);
        }
    };
}
```

and will fail to type-check. Instead you need

```
        public Void apply(String x) {
            f.accept(x);
            return null;
        }
```

same as shown in Scala by som-snytt's answer.

Now, you can ask: what happens when `Unit` is a type argument, since `void` can't be, or when the value of type `Unit` needs to be represented at runtime (one example would be `val x: Any = ()`)? In those cases `Unit` is represented by `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit` class instead, just as `Int` is usually translated to `int` but sometimes to `java.lang.Integer`. This explains why casting to `Void` throws an exception (and doesn't result in a compilation error). `Void` is not a suitable translation for these cases because it has no (non-`null`) values while `Unit` has exactly one: `()`.