# How to return java.util.Void from Scala

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, mocking, void

I am mocking an interface for testing that has a method that returns `ApiFuture[Void]` where ApiFuture is `google.com.api.core.ApiFuture` and void is the Java standard `java.util.void`. I am coding in Scala. The method doesn't return anything (it updates a hash map which stands in for the database that method is supposed to call), so my implementation of the mock returns `ApiFuture[Unit]` and throws a compile error about type mismatch. How do I get it to return `ApiFuture[Void]`?

Comment: Use `null`, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171262/convert-scala-unit-to-java-void/44172467#44172467

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Scala Unit to Java Void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171262/convert-scala-unit-to-java-void)